# Soundcloud RSS limit number of items in feed

Tags: soundcloud

Is it possible, with URL query parameters, to limit the number of items returned upon request for one's SoundCloud RSS feed?  Or, is it possible to limit the age of items returned in one's Soundcloud RSS feed?  That is,

% curl http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:NNNNNNNNN/sounds.rss?limit=10

Comment: Have you tried to attempt this or researched anything?

Comment: I don't find any documentation on customizing the SoundCloud RSS feed on their sites (creator or developer), though there is good documentation of how to set up your account to have an RSS feed.  I've tried using very obvious parameters as in the example.  The SoundCloud tech team advises using this site as the forum for questions, thus the post.  Thanks!